# How to call a particular div using html hyperlink from anothr page?

Tags: html, css

```
 <a href="something.html#div2">some</a>
```

something.html

```
 <div id="div1">IMAGES</div>
 <div id="div2"> content</div>
```

The problem is i have few images in div 1 tag.when i click `href` it doesn't go to div2 .code is working properly if div1 contains text alone.my problem is my div1 has few images.So when i click my `href` it doesn't goes to div2

Comment: It should. Your code is correct. Are you sure the page is large enough to be able to scroll? You don't accidentally have multiple elements with  `id="div2"`? Does the location bar indeed have #div2 at the end after the jump?

Comment: [Here, a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/5rqy01m3/).

Comment: Mr.Lister code works fine from the same page..but my problem the link has to clicked from other page

Comment: The fiddles I made work fine too. (In case you don't realise, two different fiddles count as two pages!) My point was, the HTML in the question should work, so there must be something else, something you're not showing in the question, that interferes with things. What is it? You'll need a more complete example that shows where things go wrong. Give a link to the website if necessary.